# Store and compare variables inside a loop - python

Tags: python, for-loop, variables

how to compare several input results inside a for loop in python? I'm trying to store the result in a new variable, but i don't know how exactly to do that. Help pls. Here is my tiny code:

```
n = int(input())
diff1 = -10000
sum_num = 0

for i in range (1, n + 1) :
    num1 = int(input())
    num2 = int(input())
    sum_num1 = num1 + num2
```

here i have to compare sum_num1 with the other n number of input sums and also i have to find the biggest difference between two subsequent input sums (e.g. sum_num1[1] = 3, sum_num1[2] = 5, so thedifference is 2) and num. I wrote my logic, but I think it's very wrong.

```
diff = abs(sum_num - sum_num1)
if diff > diff1 :
    diff1 = diff
```

Comment: Please an sample input and the expectec output. That is unclear what you tried to do, you didn't really explain

Comment: OK, i have 3 pairs of input: 1 , 2 then 3, 5 then 5 , 8, I have to check if 1+2 == 3+5 == 5+8

Comment: Then i have to check the greatest difference between 1+2 and  3+5   and also between 3+5 and 5+8. And many more checks if we have many input pairs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have to check the sums of two inputs - num1 + num1 for several pairs or num1 and num2. I cannot be more specific

Answer (score 0):

I am still a little unclear what you are after. My first suggestion would be to separate out your input data gathering from your algorithm as this will make it much easier to test.

I believe for your input data, you are trying to collect a list of pairs, so something like this:

```
input_data = [
    (1, -1),
    (0, 3),
    (15, -1),
]
```

Updating your code minimally, this can be collected like this:

```
user_input_count = int(input())
user_input_data = [(int(input()), int(input())) for i in range(user_input_count)]
print(user_input_data)
```

Assuming this is the format you are expecting, from your comments, I think you are want a two step calculation, first taking the different between the pairs, then maximising the distance between two neighbouring outputs, so something like:

```
input_data = [
    (1, -1),
    (0, 3),
    (15, -1),
]

expected_sum_num = [2, 3, 16]
expected_max_diff = 13
```

given these expected outputs, we can write an algorithm and test we get the expected results:

```
input_data = [
    (1, -1),
    (0, 3),
    (15, -1),
]

expected_sum_num = [2, 3, 16]
expected_max_diff = 13

def calc_sum_num(data):
    return [abs(a - b) for a, b in data]

def calc_max_diff(data):
    return max((abs(data[i] - data[i + 1]) for i in range(len(data) - 1)))

assert expected_sum_num == calc_sum_num(input_data)
assert expected_max_diff == calc_max_diff(expected_sum_num)
```

hence:

```
result = calc_max_diff(calc_sum_num(input_data)))
```

Let me know if I have misunderstood what you are asking. If I have, it would be useful if you could provide some examples of `input_data`, `expected_sum_num` and `expected_max_diff` values.

As background, this approach is a typical unit testing pattern where you tests algorithms with inputs and expected outputs. I have chosen not to confuse this post by including any unit testing frameworks, but if you are interested I would recommend you look at [the python standard library unittest framework](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html), or [pytest (another popular unittesting framework for python)](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/)

Comment: I think max_diff here is the maximum difference between all sum_num - sum_num1, but i need the maximum difference between 2 subsequent pairs. Here are some inputs and the result: n = int(input()) -> 3
num1 = int(input()) -> 1
num2 = int(input()) -> -1
num1 = int(input()) -> 0
num1 = int(input()) -> 3
num1 = int(input()) -> 15
num1 = int(input()) -> -1
Then sum_num1 == 2, next sum_num1 == 3 and the last sum_num1 == 16, so sum_num - sum_num1 in my case should be 16-3= 13, not 16-2=14. The other check that i have to do is between all sum_num1 for all pairs, which is an if...else...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```py
n = int(input())

inputs = [int(input()) + int(input()) for _ in range(n)]
print(max(abs(inputs[i] - inputs[i + 1]) for i in range(len(inputs) - 1)))
```

for each iteration you take two input and sum them to create list `inputs`.

Now these are the numbers you want to do the subtraction with. Every item with its next item.